# Trying to replicate excel graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

Looking for help making a graph in R with example data below.  I am trying to make the same graph as in the picture but in R. When I try to replicate it the blue line becomes vertical and not is not horizontal despite the data. The orange line plots ok though. The larger dataset has multiple stations so thats why I also include facets in my code.

[image]

(R graph uses the whole data set hence the curves do not match)

Here is my R code as well. Can someone please help? Thank you.

```
ggplot(TS, aes(X, Y, group=Station, colour=factor(Type))) + 
  facet_grid(~Station) + geom_line(size = 1) + xytheme 


   Y    X   Type    Station
2.13    0   Blue    1
2.13    50  Blue    1
2.13    100 Blue    1
3.67    0   Orange  1
3.17    10  Orange  1
2.94    15  Orange  1
1.58    20  Orange  1
1.25    35  Orange  1
1.02    46  Orange  1
0.99    65  Orange  1
0.52    74  Orange  1
0.2     82  Orange  1
0.1     91  Orange  1
0.22    100 Orange  1
```

Comment: Take out `group=Station` and the `facet_grid`, you only have one Station so it's not needed.

Comment: I have multiple stations as mentioned in the text....

Answer (score 1):

you should take "group=station" from the aes();

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)        
TS <- data.frame(y=c(2.13,2.13,2.13,3.67,3.17,2.94,1.5,1.2,1.0,0.99,0.52,0.2,0.1),
               x=c(0,50,100,0,10,15,20,35,46,65,74,82,91),
               type=c("blue","blue","blue", "orange","orange","orange","orange",
                      "orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange"),
               station=1)

    ggplot(TS, aes(x, y, colour=factor(type))) + geom_line(size = 1) + theme_excel()
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: FIXED!!  Thank you Elio Diaz!

Comment: If the answer helped you, please vote it up and accept it.